# Sum of integrals for time-ordered products

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

Say I have a sum of $n$ time-ordered products in the following way:
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{T}\left[A(t_{1})O(t_{2})...O(t_{k})...O(t_{n})\right] +...+\hat{T}\left[O(t_{1})O(t_{2})...A(t_{k})...O(t_{n})\right] + ...\hat{T}\left[O(t_{1})O(t_{2})...O(t_{k})...A(t_{n})\right]
\end{eqnarray}
where $\hat{T}$ is the time-ordering operator, and with $[O(t),O(t')]\neq 0$ and $[O(t),A(t')]\neq 0$. Is there a way to evaluate such expression? In this case, the $\hat
T$ operator can be taken out to the left of all the summed terms, but still these terms do not commute with each other in general. My doubt comes because eventually, I want to compute the integrals of these products; say:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{f}}\prod_{s=1}^{n}dt_{s} \hat{T}\left[O(t_{1})O(t_{2})...A(t_{s})...O(t_{n})\right]
\end{eqnarray}
in the same way as for the standard unitary evolution operator $U(t_{f},t_{0})$, and will correspond to the middle of the terms above. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the ordering of operators in each of these terms is fixed by time ordering, so the only difference between each of these terms is which time appears in the $A$. But if you are then simply integrating over all of the $t$s (and treating them all the same), then the final result should just be $n$ time the integral of any one of these terms

Comment: That was my suspicion, so for instance if I take $n\hat{T}[A(t_{1})O(t_{2})...O(t_{n})]$ as the final sum term, could one predetermine the order of $A(t_{1})$ by fixing $t_{1}$ to be less than any combination of theg ${t_{2},t_{3},...,t_{n}}$ set, and therefore drop it out of the $T$ action? I think this last step might somehow be wrong, because $t_{1}$ can take any order respect to the other t's in principle.

Comment: Do you mean sum or product in the eqs/title?

Comment: I mean a sum of integrals, were the integrand is given by a single term out of the $n$ terms above. The integral is then over ${t_{1},...,t_{n}}$ variables, but there are $n$ of them depending on where $A(t)$ lies in the product (which is just $n$ times one single integral as the comment above mentioned).